# Java to JSP - How do I integrate a Java application into a JSP web page?

Tags: java, jsp

Okay, this is got to be the easiest question of the day. This is my first stab at Java and JSP.

I just wrote a little Java application using using Eclipse.  Now I want to serve up this little application into a web page.  I need to figure out the connection between Java applications and web pages.

Here's my application:

```
public class PhraseOMatic {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // CREATE WORD ARRAYS
    String[] wordListOne = {"24/7", "Multi-tier", "30,000 foot", "B-to-B", "win-win", "front-end", "back-end", "web-based"};
    String[] wordListTwo = {"empowered", "sticky", "concentric", "distributed", "leveraged", "shared", "accelerated", "aligned"};
    String[] wordListThree = {"process", "tipping point", "mindshare", "mission", "space", "paradigm", "portal", "vision"};

    // CALCULATE ARRAY LENGTHS
    int oneLength = wordListOne.length;
    int twoLength = wordListTwo.length;
    int threeLength = wordListThree.length;


    // PRINT OUT THE PHRASE
    int i = 1;
    while (i < 10) {
        // GENERATE RANDOM NUMBERS
        int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * oneLength);
        int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * twoLength);
        int rand3 = (int) (Math.random() * threeLength);

        // BUILD A PHRASE
        String phrase = wordListOne[rand1] + " " + wordListTwo[rand2] + " " + wordListThree[rand3];

        // PRINT OUT PHRASE
        System.out.println("What we need is a " + phrase + ".");
        i = i + 1;

    }   

}
```

}

How to I get the compiled application to render as a web page? What steps do I need to take next?

Thanks!!!

Comment: I think what you need is a web-based distributed process.

Comment: Are you sure I don't need a B-to-B leveraged portal?

Comment: The missing link is the servlet: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) You have to define a class with some methods that returns some results. For example

```
package example;
public class WordLength {

private String word="";
public int length=0;

public WordLength(){}

public void setWord(String w){
    word = w;
    length = word.length();
}

public String getWord(){
    return word;
}

public int getLength(){
    return length;
}

}
```

2) You have to compile the java file and generate a `.class`. You can do it by using the command `javac`. Otherwise you can look in the folders of you eclipse workspace, and in the folder of the project you will find the `.class`generated from eclipse.

3)Put this file in a folder called `WEB_INF\classes\example` that stays in the root of your tomcat documents folder. (example is the name of the package)

4)In your jsp file import the java class and use it:

```
<!-- wordLegth.jsp -->

<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" %>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Word length</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <jsp:useBean id="counter" scope="session" class="example.WordLength"/>

    <% 
      String w1= request.getParameter("p1"); 
      int l1 = 0;
      counter.setWord(w1);
      l1 = counter.getLength();
    %>

    <p> The word <%= w1 %> has <%= l1 %> characters.</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

This example is automatically invoked by a form that ask the user to insert a word:

```
<!-- form.html -->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <form action="wordLegth.jsp">

      <p> Word 1: <input name="p1"></p>
      </p>
      <input type="submit" value="Count">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Regards,
Luca

Answer (score 2):

You have to return a string, in this case a nice phrase. To do this, do not use `System.out.println`, as it sends the string to the standard output. We want the string on a webpage, so this is not good to have.

Use a `StringBuilder` to collect your phrases. Return it as an array of strings, `String[]`.

As the previous paragraph suggests, we need to get rid of the `main`-method: I think this `static` method will suffice: `PhraseOMatic.generatePhrases()`.

Then, create a JSP page, see [this tutorial](http://www.jsptut.com/Dynexpr.jsp).

```
<%
     for(String phrase : PhraseOMatic.generatePhrases()) {
         out.println(phrase);
         out.println("<br/>");
     }
%>
```