# The value for the useBean class attribute is invalid

Tags: java, jsp

I am a beginner in JSP. I have the following java code, which needs to face the internet, so I am using JSP. My java code is running properly.
I have searched about this problem and found some corrections. But still it is coming.

```
<jsp:useBean id="counter" scope="session" class="Generation.SandhiGeneration"/>
```

1. 'Generation' is the package name
2. I put the class file- 'SandhiGeneration'  in WEB-INF\classes\Generation
3. I have also added the public constructor

   ```
   public SandhiGeneration(){}
   ```
4. I have some text files which will be processed by the java code so I put them inside WEB-INF\classes\Generation

I have already mention that I am novice in JSP.I have been using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892798/java-to-jsp-how-do-i-integrate-a-java-application-into-a-jsp-web-page) 
  So, please tell me where I am wrong elaborately if possible.
it is throwing error

```
 The value for the useBean class attribute Generation.SandhiGeneration is invalid.
```

Every answer will be appreciated. Thanks in advance .

Comment: Can you show the entire SandhiGeneration.java file please?

Comment: I think you need to show your entire project structure and the listing for SandhiGeneration.java for people to help you further with this one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is where you have placed your `bean class SandhiGeneration`. If you are working on NetBeans, place your `SandhiGeneration.java` file in

```
/Source Packages/Generation/SandhiGeneration
```

i.e. make a package named `Generation` under `SourcePackages` and put your java file under this package.

Comment: Thanks for your first reply.
I am using tomcat. . I made the java code in eclipse. I have tried your solution. I made a folder 'Source Package' inside classes folder. and put the generation folder in Source Package. and made another folder-SandhiGeneration inside the generation and put the .java file inside it.the .class file is inside Generation.

Comment: You don't have to make `Source Package`.Just right click on your project..make a new folder name `Generation` and put your java class under that folder

Comment: For creating new package refer [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sbo-D3P6GNg) video