# How to run a main method in java after pressing a button in a jsp?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I'm new to this. I need to make a jsp to upload a CSV file and send the data in it to a mysql database. I made a code in Java to get the latter part done, but not sure how to connect it to the jsp, so when the user press uploads the java code runs.

My java code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class dbInserter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String jdbcURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDb";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "1234";

        String csvFilePath = "C:/Users/Name/Desktop/Attendance.csv";

        int batchSize = 20;

        Connection connection = null;

        try {

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, username, password);
            connection.setAutoCommit(false);

            String sql = "INSERT INTO csv (name, `in-time`, `out-time`) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFilePath));
            String lineText = null;

            int count = 0;

            lineReader.readLine(); // skip header line

            while ((lineText = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] data = lineText.split(",");
                String name = data[0];
                String inTime = data[1];
                String outTime = data[2];

                statement.setString(1, name);
                statement.setString(2, inTime);
                statement.setString(3, outTime);

                statement.addBatch();

                if (count % batchSize == 0) {
                    statement.executeBatch();
                }
            }

            lineReader.close();

            // execute the remaining queries
            statement.executeBatch();

            connection.commit();
            connection.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

            try {
                connection.rollback();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I tried using a servlet, but since I have very little experience using it, I ran into many errors. Would really appreciate it  if someone can help me with this.

Comment: This should help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6892798/java-to-jsp-how-do-i-integrate-a-java-application-into-a-jsp-web-page